# The file "/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" does not exist

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

When Ever a launch application this error come out `The file "/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" does not exist.` after i tried to add a new library using eclipse(UNIX MAC OS).

Comment: please provide more details...

Comment: i added the source folder from this link (https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm )using steps =>  Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python > Libraries and clicked Apply followed by OK, after that this error comes out every time i launch app

Comment: Sorry that was my bad.... i changed the dierectory of google_appengine...thats why this error comes out... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this message is because the file `dev_appserver.py` doesn't exist at the location `/usr/local/google_appengine`.

You need to install the [Google App Engine Python SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the spotlight (Cmd + Space), find and run GoogleAppEngineLauncher. It will create a link to google_appengine in your local folder. Then you should restart Eclipse or Pycharm (my favorite). Create need project again if necessary.